# Px matrix library for RGB led matrix 32x16 for total 30 modules for larger display

Tags: rgb, esp8266, esp8266wifi

1. I am unable to increase the brightness using display.brightness(255)
2. anyone help me regarding this display.begin(8 or 4 or etc...) if i want to keep 30 modules of 32x16 .Am not understanding about scan pattern????
3. what is display.setMuxpattern()????

anyone please explain me about this

Thankyou in advance

to increase brightness i changed value to 255 in display.brightness(255) but there is not tha much change in it.
then i changed colour depth to 6 ****#define PxMATRIX_COLOR_DEPTH 6 **** then it started flickering but brightness increased.